# Match multiple users in 'sshd_config'

Tags: ssh, users, configuration, sshd

I'm trying to apply the same `sshd` settings to multiple users.

According to the manual, it seems `Match User` acts like an `AND`:

> Introduces a conditional block. If all of the criteria on the `Match` line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file

How do I state "for any of these users...", so in this example `bob`, `joe`, and `phil` are allowed to use SSH as a proxy, but not allowed to log in:

```
Match User bob, User joe, User phil
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowTCPForwarding yes
    ForceCommand /bin/echo 'We talked about this guys. No SSH for you!'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not having done this myself, I can only go on what the manuals say:

From the `sshd_config` manual:

> The match patterns may consist of single entries or
> comma-separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation
> operators described in the PATTERNS section of `ssh_config(5)`.

This means that you ought to be able to say

```
Match User bob,joe,phil
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  AllowTCPForwarding yes
  ForceCommand /bin/echo 'We talked about this guys. No SSH for you!'
```

Note that "comma-separated" means no additional spaces should be inserted between the names.

See also this answer on the Information Security forum: [Creating user specific authentication methods in SSH](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18038).

Comment: Important detail, no spaces between the users (eg. after the comma) are allowed

Comment: @ManuelManhart No, exactly; the names are supposed to be *comma-separated*, as mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Match directive on a group instead of a user.
Then add the users to that group

```
Match Group users_with_no_ssh
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowTCPForwarding yes
    ForceCommand /bin/echo 'We talked about this guys. No SSH for you!'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure ForceCommand would work well with SFTP. Also, maybe it's better to see 'DenyUsers' word in logs. Anyway, I use this (well, maybe it would be better to use Group):

sshd_config

```
# support, ansible & backup only from specific IP                                                                    
Match User ansible,backup,support Address *,!176.x.x.x                                                          
      DenyUsers ansible,backup,support

Match User backup
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        AllowAgentForwarding yes
        PermitListen 127.0.0.1:2223
        AcceptEnv RESTIC_REPOSITORY RESTIC_PASSWORD
```

Testing configuration

```
# sshd -T -C addr=176.x.x.x,user=backup | egrep '^((deny|allow)users|permitlisten|acceptenv)'
denyusers root
acceptenv RESTIC_REPOSITORY
acceptenv RESTIC_PASSWORD
permitlisten 127.0.0.1:2223

# sshd -T -C addr=8.8.4.4,user=backup | egrep '^((deny|allow)users|permitlisten|acceptenv)' 
denyusers ansible,backup,support
acceptenv RESTIC_REPOSITORY
acceptenv RESTIC_PASSWORD
permitlisten 127.0.0.1:2223
```

Real world test

```
Jan 29 16:50:12 mx1 sshd[71309]: Connection from 199.x.x.x port 21042 on 199.x.x.x port 2222 rdomain "0"   
Jan 29 16:50:13 mx1 sshd[71309]: User support from 199.x.x.x not allowed because listed in DenyUsers
Jan 29 16:50:13 mx1 sshd[71309]: Connection closed by invalid user support 199.x.x.x port 21042 [preauth]
```

Comment: ForceCommand works on sftp too. That is how we enable Duo 2fa within our organization.